# form within reactive form

Tags: angular, forms

The first form is the parent and inside it I have another form that became necessary because the attributes are the same as those in the parent form.

I was doing it this way

```
<div formControlName="pessoa">
    <div [formGroup]="formPessoa" class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
            <msp-input-text id="nome" label="Nome"></msp-input-text>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
            <msp-input-text id="idade" label="Idade" maxLenght="2"></msp-input-text>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and FormBuild Constructor

```
 pessoa: this.formPessoa,
```

And form

```
 this.formPessoa = this.formBuilder.group({
          nome: [null],
          idade: [null],
        });
```

but he gives me a browser error

```
No value accessor for form control with name: 'pessoa'
```

thank you for any help

Comment: Assuming those are ControlValueAccessor inputs, you’ll need to add formControlName=“pessoa” to that input component.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: No wait.. forget that.. you have other issues here

Comment: I’d need to see the complete component and html.. but what you’re trying is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the code with below code. I mentioned the changes in the comment -

1. Remove this line -  `pessoa: this.formPessoa`
2. Initialize this form in either in constructor or ngOnInit.
3. 

```
<div [formGroup]="formPessoa">                             // Add formGroup directive
 <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
    <msp-input-text formControlName="nome"></msp-input-text>    // Add formControlName for input
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
    <msp-input-text maxLenght="2" formControlName="idade"></msp-input-text>    // Add formControlName for input
  </div>

</div>
```